# Can't set properties in Custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I made a custom table view cell - i have a header, implementation, and nib. In the nib I set the style to custom, dragged a label on it and made an outlet in the nibs file owner.

From my UITableView Controller I have this code:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"adbActivityCell";

adbActivityCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (!cell) {
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellIdentifier owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    //cell =[[adbActivityCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

cell.price.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell #%d", indexPath.item + 1];

return cell;
```

If I run this as is XCode tells me that the UITableView Controller is not key value compliant for the label property (the label is named "price"). If I comment out the two lines above and uncomment that one line my application runs, but the label doesn't show up at all, even if I set default text for it.

I've spent quite a lot of time researching tutorials and questions on here with no luck.

Comment: if you connect the lable outlet to file owner then dont do that connect to the custom cell itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Its all about view hierarchy.

You have to add your label outlet to the custom UITableViewCell, because it is the superView of your label in view heirarchy.

That means label is contained in custom cell thats why you have add outlet to custom cell.

```
self.view->tableView->CustomCellView->UILabel
```

Comment: Right, so your suggest works, but now this means that it's impossible to create an outlet from IB, I would first need to create the property in the header file manually and then hook up the connection through IB?

Comment: If the files owner and the custom uitablecell are the same class then I don't understand why hooking up the connection between the two isn't exactly the same.

Comment: custom cell is the files owner for label

Answer (score -1):

In your customCell.h file set the IBOutlet of the label. Your problem will be solved.